# The probability that no person has the same birthday month

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

> If there are $12$ people in the room what the chances are that no two people will have the same birthday month?

**I tried to think of it in this way:**

The total number of options is $12^{12}$

The option that no one will have the same birthday month is:

$12 * 11 * ... 1$ which means $12!$

So I think the answer is:

$$\frac{12!}{12^{12}}=0.0000537$$

What do you think?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks good.  Of course, you are assuming that all months are equally likely, which isn't technically true (even if you assume all birthdays are equally likely).   Good approximation though.

Comment: I think this is correct.

Comment: Yaaa! **Thanks!**

Comment: Related to `http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770997/`.

Comment: It's not the same, the post you linked has the same birthday month

Comment: I solved pretty much the same question earlier today (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712328/birthday-enumeration-question/1712990#1712990)

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475378/what-is-the-probability-that-nobody-is-born-in-the-same-month

Answer (score 2):

Just to close the question:

Assuming each person's birth month is independent and each month is equally likely, then your calculation of $\frac{12!}{12^{12}}\approx 0.0000537$ is correct

Incidentally,  $\frac{n!}{n^{n}}$ is close to $\sqrt{2 \pi n}\, e^{-n}$ for large $n$, and for $n=12$ would give about $0.0000534$

Answer (score 0):

You can think about this in terms of conditional probability. Let $E_1$ be "first person have a birthday", which is obviously $P(E_1) = 1$. Then, let $E_2$ be "second person have a birthday on a different month than first person". $P(E_2|E_1) = \frac{11}{12}$, since second person have 11 different months to "choose" from. Then, you have $P(E_3|E_1 \cap E_2) = \frac{10}{12}$, $P(E_4|E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3) = \frac{9}{12}$, and so on. Then $$P(E_1 \cap \dots \cap E_{12}) = P(E_1) \cdot P(E_2|E_1) \cdot \dots \cdot P(E_{12}|E_1 \cap \dots \cap E_{11}) = 1 \cdot \frac{11}{12} \cdot \dots \cdot \frac{1}{12} = \frac{12!}{12^{12}}$$